# Docker Container not accessible through Container IP

Tags: docker

i have installed Docker "Docker for Windows Installer" for windows 10 64 bit. I have running hyper -v as virtual system that is default.

I have few questions.

1. If I have installed docker with virtual box. I need to create docker-machine by command line but when i am using hyper -v. I don't need docker-machine to get installed. I think it is automatically installed when using hyper-v.(I am assuming because i tried to hello world example. It is pulling images and creating container). But in case of "hyper-v" I can't check what is ip of docker-machine.

> C:\Users\indiverkumar>docker-machine ip
>
> Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists

In case of virtual box. I had to create docker-machine by myself(docker-machine create default). So when I try to get IP address of docker-machine. It shows me IP address.

**Question** : How would i get IP address of docker-machine in case of hyper-v.
**Question** : When i tried to check IP address of docker container([Mario Docker Image)](https://hub.docker.com/r/pengbai/docker-supermario/) by **docker inspect container_id**. It is showing me 172.17.0.2. But when i am trying to check 172.17.0.2:8080.(launched container is tomcat web application running on 8080 port). It is not accessible. Even I have disabled firewall.

If I have not mapped port with docker machine. It should work with the help of container IP. But it is not working.(After checking 172.17.0.2:8080)

After Mapping port i must have two IP address one with local host(that is working) and other with the help of docker-machine IP.
Like this **http://localhost:8080 or http://host-ip:8080**

**Summary**

I assume each Docker container should be accessible from localhost /host-ip/container-ip.

Answer (score -1):

No, the way Docker works is that you can open up ports on your container allowing you to use them on the host machine address.

---

**Example:** Create a docker container with the open tcp port of 8080, then run a web server (eg. Django, Express, Gin) on the port 8080, then go to :8080 and view the app.

Comment: Yes. I have opened up the port. But with localhost i am able to access that. So it should be accessible through host-ip and container-ip. Don't you think. I just checked an open issue that hyper-v docker nat ethernet adaptor in windows 10 64 bit it is not showing ip address and when i checked ipconfig. DockerNAT ethernet adaptor is showing empty default gateway. Can this be reason why i am not able to access through container ip as well as hostip

Comment: Docker has several built-in modes of networking and possibility to use other drivers https://docs.docker.com/network/